# how to do datagridview pagination with mongodb in c#? or how to do pagination without database?

Tags: c#, mongodb, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

Here i tried the code,but it is not working
   private void btn_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        scr_val = scr_val - 5;
        if(scr_val<=0)
        {
            scr_val = 0;

        }
        MongoClient t= new MongoClient();


        if (this.CurrentPageIndex < this.TotalPage)
        {
            this.CurrentPageIndex++;
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource =
        Results(this.CurrentPageIndex);
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: There's not enough info to help you easily, please show the data you get back from Mongo

Comment: {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5936d17263623919cd5165bd"),
        "name" : "Lisa Rogers",
        "marks" : 34
    }